# How to draw area chart in Android using MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am looking for a way to draw area chart using MPAndroidChart. I am aware , I can use StackedBar Chart but that doesn't quite serve the purpose.
Is there a way to draw Area chart such as shown below using MPAndroidChart and if not what might be the suitable alternate?

[sample image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_chart#/media/File:De_wanderung.svg) souce-wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make chart as you want using MPAndroidChart.

I tested using sample app in google Play Store(try search 'MPAndroidChart').

try multiLineChart and make option Toggle Filled. I think this is what you're looking for.

[image]